# How can I connect my data to GoodData and for which purpose can I use them?

Tags: gooddata

what methods of connection does GoodData offer?  I mean internet, virtual private network, direct data circuits, etc. And what kind of connection can I use for which purpose?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For data upload, there is a variety of options (as documented here: https://www.gooddata.com/data-sources/). For platform usage / end user access, HTTPS protocol is used. In both cases, standard Internet connection (fully encrypted in transit using the state-of-art cryptographic protocols and cipher suites) is used but we do have customers who are using a VPN connection for the data upload.